# Get the values of a column and use it to delete a record in database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I have a table in my database where i have a boolean field. I want to check its value and use it further for deleting record in another table...

Dummy Code is like this:

```
private sub del_Machine()

 Dim machine_srno as string
 Dim asql As String = ("SELECT * FROM Installation_det")
 cnnOLEDB.Open()
 Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(asql, cnnOLEDB)
 Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
 If dr.Read = True Then
    if IsTFT.checked=true then      ----------> IsTFT is a column in Installation_det table
     machine_srno=Machine.value ------------> Machine is also a field in database

    DeleteQuery = "DELETE * FROM new_table WHERE sr_no=@mach_srno"
            Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(DeleteQuery,    cnnOLEDB)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mach_srno", machine_srno)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

end sub
```

Please help me for actual coding... I think it will be help ful wit data table and data set but dont know how exactly to use it.. please suggest me with code... Thank You..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the values from the DataReader and then use them for your query

```
If dr.Read = True Then
    Dim isTFT = Convert.ToBoolean(dr("IsTFT"))
    Dim machine_srno = dr("Machine").ToString()
    if isTFT = True Then
        Dim DeleteQuery = "DELETE * FROM new_table WHERE sr_no=@mach_srno"
        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(DeleteQuery,    cnnOLEDB)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mach_srno", machine_srno)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End If
ENd If
```

Comment: Thank You Very much Steve.... I was Using this code:                ` Dim tftno As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("sr_no")                             
 Dim machno As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Machine_srno")
                    Dim xsql As String = "DELETE * FROM new_table WHERE Sr_no=@tftno OR Sr_no=@machno  ".....     So I was stuck over 1st Line... Your Code is perfectly working... Thanks Ones Again..

Comment: Hi @Steve... can you please help me with a new question i have just posted.... its Title is "how to update data from one access database by importing periodically from another database in vb.net"  Please help me with that problem... Thank you